# Retrieve global variable after test run in Jest

Tags: jestjs

Is it possible to retrieve a global variable from the test environment?

For example (pseudo code):

*test.js*

```
global.foo = 'bar';
```

*Call jest using the API:*

```
import { runCLI } from 'jest';
runCLI({
      config: config,
      runInBand: true,
      silent: true
  }, [process.cwd()]).then(result => {
  result.globals.foo //=> somehow retrieve globals?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `runCLI` [resolves](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-cli/src/cli/index.js#L62) with two arguments, an `AggregatedResult` type and a `GlobalConfig` type. `AggregatedResult` doesn't contain anything pertinent, and [`GlobalConfig`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/types/Config.js) only contains information on the globals that were set in  jest.config.js.

`runCLI` is undocumented, but it seems that the answer is no, there is not a way to see the global that a particular test was run directly through that object.

Comment: You are correct. I ended up opening an issue. It is something the team wants to support in the future. Worth keeping an eye on: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7421